# WPF Saving UI settings to .txt file

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have a window with configurable controls where I can reposition them or hide them during runtime. Now my goal is to save current state of controls so whenever user closes an app and opens it again window shows last configuration of controls. I'm saving XAML to .txt file and then reading that file. Is it good/safe approach to use that kind of method? Are there better methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question will most likely be closed for being opinion-based, but I would recommend saving your control states to the built-in WPF User Settings file that comes with your project, instead of creating your own.  There's nothing wrong with creating your own, but why build your own parser when Visual Studio has already provided one for you.  You will find this file under your project's Properties->Settings.settings file.  This file gets automatically loaded when ever the user launches your WPF app.  This file is stored in your %LocalAppData% folder, under the appropriate Company name and Product name, if you specified one.

Let's say the Settings.settings file contains the following states that you want to save:

[image]

Then in your code, find the appropriate time to load these settings into your app's variables:

```
// Load 
string lastUser = Properties.Settings.Default.LastUser;
bool detailsEnabled = Properties.Settings.Default.ShowDetails;
int timeout = Properties.Settings.Default.FormTimeoutSeconds;
```

And when you want to save the control states, such as when the user closes your app, or changes a state value, do this:

```
// Save settings
Properties.Settings.Default.LastUser = lastUser;
Properties.Settings.Default.ShowDetails = detailsEnabled;
Properties.Settings.Default.FormTimeoutSeconds = timeout;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! But I have a question, in my case i have a multiple UniformGrids and these exact controlls are configurable, which type I should choose in settings menu?

Comment: What about these UniformGrids are you saving to your txt file right now?  Is it the ColumnSpacing and RowSpacing?  Those are just integers, as far as I'm concerned.  Try to break down the UniformGrid things that you are trying to save into something simple: an int, string, or bool.  I can't imaging it needing anything more than that.  If this answers your question, consider marking my post as an "answer".  Best of luck to you.